# react-router switch not working as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-component

I'm learning react and got stuck at react-routes

consider the following:

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

import HelloWorld from "./HelloWorld.jsx";

const Root = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={HelloWorld} />
          <Route component={NoMatch} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

function NoMatch({ location }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>
        No match found
      </h3>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Root;
```

on '/' this route, it renders `HelloWorld` component as expected but on other routes for examples `abc` it displays `Cannot GET /abc` instead of `No match found`

Comment: Does `<Route path="*" component={NoMatch} />` work?

Comment: Nope, issue still persist

Comment: which version or `react-router-dom` are you using?

Comment: it's react-router-dom@4.3.1

Comment: are you getting there via a `Link` component (from React Router) or direct through the url? If direct, can you make a `Link` to '/abc' and see what happens?

Comment: it turns out my code is fine but webpack.config.js requires this `devServer: {historyApiFallback: true,}` for react routes to work, don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code works just fine if you used `create-react-app` for setting up the react project but if you're using webpack configurations for manually setting up the project it requires `devServer: {historyApiFallback: true,}` for react routes to work.

Comment: Thank you, man. I used eject in create-react-app and without this option which I added manually, the Switch component didn't work

Comment: This answer needs more upvote, I didn't use create-react-app but made react project with webpack configuration, just added this option to webpack _immediately_ solves my issue.

Comment: I copy/pasted some CRA React project and turned into Vite one, but it seems this is my problem. I still can't figure how to solve it, but I think its related to this

Answer (score 4):

First you check your react version then after do like this if v5.1 and above

In order to use v6, you'll need to convert all your  elements to `<Routes>`

You want to replace component to element into <Route ...>

example:- App.js

```
import Home from "./Home";
import About from "./About";

import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}


export default App;
```

after that your switch related error maybe gone!
if still not working comment me i will help you

Comment: That's work for me thanks

Answer (score 3):

This happens because your server is not set up to handle those routes specifically.  The server it what determines what exists and what doesn't - react-router is just a tool to exploit it a bit.

**Fix 1**

You can avoid this issue by importing `HashRouter` from the react-router-dom package, rather than `BrowserRouter`.

The result will be routing based on URLs with a `#/` prepending the route itself.  So your route of `/` will now actually be `#/`.

**Fix 2**

Set up a reverse proxy (`nginx`) as the intermediary to serve your page from the Node.js server.  Use a broad wildcard or get specific if you know you need more specific configurations.  It will pass along the request URI/path to node still but not try to use them as separate endpoints each time or read files from the file system.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be working fine for me with latest React and react-router-dom.

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

const HelloWorld = () => {
return <div>Hello World</div>;
};

const Root = () => {
return (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
            <Switch>
                <Route path='/' exact component={HelloWorld} />
                <Route component={NoMatch} />
            </Switch>
        </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

function NoMatch() {
  return (
    <div>
        <h3>No match found</h3>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Root;
```

[Code sandbox link to try it out](https://codesandbox.io/s/3x8350lqx6)

Comment: Thanks for the solution, actually I was using webpack configurations instead of create-react-app so webpack config requires `devServer: {historyApiFallback: true,}` for react routes. I don't what it does but adding this in webpack config file resolves the issue.

Comment: historyApiFallback always sends responses to your index. It's required for BrowserRouter on SPAs. The HashRouter can work without the historyApiFallback, but you get those ugly hashes /#/ inside your uri.

Comment: Thanks, I was using a CRA project with React Router 5, and pass it to Vite, but changing the Router with BrowserRouter did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

From react-router-dom-v6 Switch have been replaced with Routes. Import Routes from react-router-dom and use all route as a child of Routes...

From:

```
<Switch>
  <Route/>
</Switch>
```

To:

```
<Routes>
   <Route />
</Routes>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into the sandbox it will help you:

https://codesandbox.io/s/py114mqzj0

Please upgrade your dependencies as follows:

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "16.5.2",
    "react-dom": "16.5.2",
    "react-router-dom": "4.3.1",
},
```