# One router work but other router not work

Tags: reactjs

Hey i have a reactjs app with this as app.tsx

```
    import tw from 'twin.macro';
    import { hot } from 'react-hot-loader/root';
    import { Route, BrowserRouter as Router, Routes as Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
    import Main from './Main';
    import Test from './Test';

    const App = () => {
        return (
            <><Main /><div css={tw`mx-auto w-auto`}>
                <Router>
                    <Switch>
                    <Route path="/element" element={<Test />} />
                    <Route path="/" element={<Main />} />
                    </Switch>
                </Router>
            </div></>
        );

    };

    export default hot(App);
```

But when i run a `./node_modules/.bin/webpack --watch --progress` the `localhost/` work but `localhost/element` not work i have a 404 error
Not Found The requested URL was not found on this server
Can you tell me why its not work?

(i use 6.2.1 of react-router-dom)

Comment: Which version of react-router are you using? The behavior is not the same in v5 and v6.

Comment: (i use 6.2.1 of react-router-dom)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first and foremost you need to mention the version you are using  , and try this if it works for u :-

**your components should look like this, to work:-**

```
import tw from 'twin.macro';
    import { hot } from 'react-hot-loader/root';
    import { Route, Routes} from 'react-router-dom';
    import Main from './Main';
    import Test from './Test';

    const App = () => {
        return (
            <><Main /><div css={tw`mx-auto w-auto`}>
               
                    <Routes>
                        <Route exact  path="/element" element= {<Test />} />
                        <Route exact  path="/" element= {<Main/>} />
                    </Routes>              
            </div></>
        );

    };
```

**NB: try to wrap your index.tsx component with the `<BrowserRouter> </BrowserRouter>` like this  :**

```
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
ReactDOM.render( <BrowserRouter> <App/> </BrowserRouter>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

therefore you can remove the BrowserRouter from the app.tsx

Comment: Not work (i use 6.2.1 of react-router-dom)

Comment: is this your index.js or app.js ?

Comment: Its my app.tsx 
My index.tsx contain a reactdom render ```
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));```

Comment: well i have updated the answer please check

Comment: @Bagou450 hey i have updated the entire answer it will definitely work

Comment: Switch  not exist on last my react router dom version  see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53972254/react-router-switch-not-working-as-expected

Comment: oh no i forgot to remove the Switch , check now it will work.

Comment: Route can t have exact " La propriété 'exact' n'existe pas sur le type 'IntrinsicAttributes & LibraryManagedAttributes<(_props: PathRouteProps | LayoutRouteProps | IndexRouteProps) => ReactElement<...> | null, PathRouteProps | ... 1 more ... | " but i try without wait

Comment: mhh now its work thanks but how i can extract it to my nginx server because actualy i use
`node ./node_modules/cross-env/src/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development ./node_modules/.bin/webpack --progress` 
But route not work on web server because i have only a index.html

Comment: i really dont know about nginx server , please accept this as answer so it will be closed , you can post about nginx server as another question and hopefully you will find an answer like this one happy new year bro

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using ‘react-router-dom’ newer version. Switch is no longer in the new version. please read here
[Switch' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69843615/switch-is-not-exported-from-react-router-dom)

Comment: I write in import line "Routes as Switch " i use Routes no Switch

Answer (score 0):

```html
import { Route, BrowserRouter as Router, Routes as Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {

  const Main = () => {
    return (
      <h1>Main</h1>
    )
  } 
  
  const Test = <h1>Test</h1>

  return (
    <div >
        <Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/element" element={<Main />} />
                <Route path="/" element={Test} />
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

You need to use the `<Main />`  structure

Comment: Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

not work